# Cardboard headtracking with no gyro

Tags: google-cardboard

I have a LG G3 phone which after some testing does not have a gyroscope(only accelerometer) and I've been testing the Cardboard with it and faced some issues.

Sometimes the camera can suddently jump up to 90 degrees in any direction from where I was looking, and this can at it's worst happen every 10 seconds or so(usually about every 30sec). I did test the accelerometer output and it didn't seem to be that inaccurate that the camera would jump that much. I've looked around and found a couple of other users reporting the same issue too.

This issue is present not only in the Unity Cardboard SDK Demo but also in *some* vr apps, and by some I mean there are a couple of apps that I've tried that works perfectly fine(Can't remember which ones right now but one was a roller coaster vr app). Though this issue is really apparent in the Cardboard Labs app.

This jumpyness doesn't only destroy the immersion but also induces a bit of desorientation aswell as nausea when the jumping gets really bad. I had a hard time finishing the Cardboard Labs tests because of this...

Soo last but not least can the headtracking code be optimized for phones without a gyro so that these experiences can be improved? If not on the google side of the SDK, is there anything I can do to the SDK to help minimize this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some testing I seem to have it fixed now.
The reason seems to be that since I have rooted my device and I'm often fiddling with the frequency of the CPU in it the motion tracking somehow gets messed up. This can easily be fixed with a reboot with stock clocks.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the polling of the motion sensor fetching incorrect data when it's reading too fast or if it's the cpu that can't keep up but nevertheless, I seem to be stuck with stock clocks if I'm going to play VR games. I'm leaving this question here for those who might have the same issue.

EDIT: After some more testing the issue reappeared after a while. I'm guessing there is an app or service that might be the problem here because after a restart it's fixed again.. I'll post more when I've tested it further.